# How to fetch the profile path of chrome using c#.net program

Tags: c#

I need to capture the chrome profile path during runtime. Now I am using the code like this:

```
string google = @"C:\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"
```

Since the path may varies I do not want to hard code the full profile path but get it at runtime using c#.net.

What I have tried:

`String sourceFile1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\";`

When I tried `chrome://version/` I get the profile path but how can I used this URL in windows application form?